# setHours in different timezones

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I am comparing two dates but problem is that in my local computer generated date when i use `setHours` method like so `console.log(new Date(new Date().setHours(8)));` it gives me an output of `2020-07-22T04:41:46.624Z` my Timezone is GMT+4 (Georgia Standard Time) but on my heroku server (EU) or [repl.it](https://repl.it) it gives where timezone offset is `-0` it gives me `2020-07-22T08:41:46.624Z` for the exact same command, how can i fix this? otherwise if i log `new Date()` on both machines they all log the same date even if i add time to them, its setting hours (or minutes, etc.) that alters the timezone

Answer (score 11):

A few things:

- The `setHours` function interprets the input in the local time zone.  So yes - you will get different results depending on the time zone of the computer where you run it.  You are literally saying: "Set the hour to 8 am local time".
- If you intended to set the hour to 8 am UTC, you can use the `setUTCHours` function instead.  UTC is the same across the entire planet, so you will get the same result both locally and on your server, regardless of time zone.  (Assuming your clock is synchronized correctly by your OS.)
- The `Z` in the string output *means* [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).
- When you log a `Date` object, the resulting string format is environment specific.  In some environments, you'll get output like you showed, which is the same as if you called `toISOString` - which is in ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC.  In other environments you'll get the output that comes from `toString` - which is in a different format, and is usually based on local time.  The point is - there's no standard that controls the log output for a `Date` object.  Don't log it directly - log the string result of calling one of those two functions (probably `toISOString`).

Answer (score 0):

When you use new Date(), it sets hours to [Unix epoch][1],regardless of where you instantiate the date,it will be the same time in terms of Unix Epoch (if done at the same exact moment).

When you use setHours you change that previously created date to match specific hours on that date(still in terms of Unix epoch under the hood. The specific time set on that date by the setHours function, corresponds to your local environment and time zone.

Time zones and time are complicated in JS and in the world. "Time is an illusion, lunch time doubly so". If you want to reliably set an accurate time with timezone for a specific date. You can use this function.

If you want a set hours function that also takes in an IANA timezone and sets time in

```js
const setHoursDifferentTZ=(inputDateTime, timeZone, setHoursArray)=>{

    /**
     * This funciton will setHours on a dateTime object in a non local timezone 
     * Parameters
     ** inputDateTime, a date object which you want to setHours (in a non local timezone on)
     *** Example: new Date(2023, 10, 10, 10, 30) 10:30 (localalized to user timezone) on 10/30/2023
     ** timeZone, the desired timezone you want to set the date in.
     *** Example: var timeZone = 'US/Central' 
     *** Requires a 'tz database time zone' name aka an IANA timezone name
     *** Usefull list here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
     *** Date.prototype.toLocaleString() usng IANA time zone names is widely supported
     *** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#browser_compatibility
     ** setHoursArray: a setHours parameter in array format eg var setHoursArray = [12,30]
     */
    console.log('desired Time Zone',timeZone) 
    console.log('desired Time     ',setHoursArray) 

    inputDateTime.setHours(setHoursArray[0],setHoursArray[1])

    
    const dateTZShifted = inputDateTime.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone : timeZone , dateStyle: 'long', timeStyle: 'long'})
    let timeTZShifted = dateTZShifted.split(" ").slice(4,5).join(' ').toString().split(':')
    var originalTime = inputDateTime.toString().split(" ").slice(4,5).join(' ').toString().split(':')
    let newLocalTime = [
        Number(originalTime[0]) - Number(timeTZShifted[0]) + Number(originalTime[0]) ,
        Number(originalTime[1]) - Number(timeTZShifted[1]) + Number(originalTime[1]) , 
        Number(originalTime[2]) -Number(timeTZShifted[2])  + Number(originalTime[2])
    ]
    let outputDate = new Date(inputDateTime)
    outputDate.setHours(Number(newLocalTime[0]), Number(newLocalTime[1]),Number(newLocalTime[2]))
    console.log('outputDateTime  ', outputDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone : timeZone , dateStyle: 'long', timeStyle: 'long'}) )
    return(outputDate)   
}
//Usage
var dateObject = new Date(2023, 09, 10, 10, 30)
console.log('inputDateTime  ', dateObject.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone : 'US/Central' , dateStyle: 'long', timeStyle: 'long'}) )
console.log('inputDateTime', dateObject) 

let dateHoursSetDifferentTZ = setHoursDifferentTZ(dateObject, 'US/Central', [10,30])
console.log(dateHoursSetDifferentTZ)
```

Ouput:
**inputDateTime   October 10, 2023 at 9:30:00 AM CDT**

^ Expressed as Locale (Central) string.
**inputDateTime 2023-10-10T14:30:00.000Z**

^ Expressed as UTC Time
**desired Time Zone US/Central**

desired Time      [ 10, 30 ]
**outputDateTime   October 10, 2023 at 10:30:00 AM CDT**

^ Expressed as Locale (Central) string.
**2023-10-10T15:30:00.000Z**

^ Expressed as UTC Time